# Areas of Linux for freshers

Tags: untagged

I am a fresher who recently got a job in Linux Admin - maintaining some servers for a client.  The server might  be a mix of web and app servers, could you please suggest in what areas I need to learn and excel to make sure I shine in the career.  As of now I am planning o change from VB.net to Python because Linux server might need scripting to be done in Python and Bash.  Could you please specify areas where I need to concentrate.  Right now I am only a fresher.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is a 'fresher?'

Comment: I am new to field, just trained on basic redhat linux administration skills.

Comment: Ok, I get it. It's not a specific role, but it's like saying you're new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of question is off-topic for our Q&A format.  The reason being is that it promotes extended discussion and the answer would be subjective or not easy to support with facts and evidence.

That said, I'd suggest a certification track to cover the basics.  Don't worry about specializing in particular scripting language at this point.  Try Red Hat's RHCSA to lay the foundation.

Comment: Thank you, I understand.  However, I am unclear on to what path I need to go, like Linux Security, Networking, administration, cloud front etc.  That is why I am asking this sort of a question.  Thank you.

Comment: @surpavan It's not appropriate for us to decide your own life's direction. :)

Comment: That is fine.  Thank you, I understand what you mean now, it is my choice and can be any field, just learn, implement and enjoy.  Thank you.